# Python: Program execution order is incorrect

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have following code

```
import unittest
import requests
import time
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

token = ''
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Token': token}
class ChromeSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver = cls.driver
        base_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/'
        driver.get(base_url)
        print("Generating Token")
        usernameStr = 'user1a'
        passwordStr = 'user'
        response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/auth/token', auth=(usernameStr, passwordStr))
        print(response)
        data = response.json()
        print(data)
        if response.status_code == 200 and data["status"] == "SUCCESS":
            token = data["token"]
        else:
            token = None
            print("The request was not successful.")
        print(token)

    def test_update_user_infp(self):
        print("Planning to update user's info")

        datap = {'firstname': 'Newfirstname',
        'lastname': 'Newname',
        'phone': '111000111'}

        r = requests.put('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/users/user1a', data=json.dumps(datap), headers=headers)
        print(r.text)

    def test_get_users(self):
        print("Planning to get users")

        r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/users', headers=headers)
        print"Get request for api Users"
        print(r.text)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Log are as below, if you see in logs it says `Generating Token` `Planning to get users` but gives a . and `.Planning to update user's info` authentication required, why ? It just works fine if I dont use class and def.

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55429/devtools/browser/cc53d84c-3847-40a3-b3fb-159892c71ac9
Generating Token
<Response [200]>
{u'status': u'SUCCESS', u'token': u'MjU5NzMzMDY1NTU1NzYxMTE4NjQ4NDgxMTc0OTkyMjI4NTg0NTE5'}
MjU5NzMzMDY1NTU1NzYxMTE4NjQ4NDgxMTc0OTkyMjI4NTg0NTE5
Planning to get users
Get request for api Users
{"payload":["user1a"],"status":"SUCCESS"}

.Planning to update user's info
{"message":"Token authentication required","status":"FAILURE"}

.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 5.938s

OK
```

Comment: I think you may need to pass the authentication token along with your `PUT` request to the server as an `Authorization` header. Otherwise, how would the server know that the incoming request is from an authenticated user?

Comment: @AjayDabas can a token define in set be used in other functions ?

Comment: You can do this using the attributes of a class. Declare token attribute in your `setUpClass` class like this `self.token=...` which can then be accessed in the `test_update_user_infp` method, again like this `self.token`.

Comment: @AjayDabas self-token or cls.token ?

Comment: Update: My bad, yes it should be `cls.token` since you named it `cls`. Common practice is `self` though.

Comment: @AjayDabas how we can use self? when you see classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls): has cls ?

Comment: @AjayDabas ok it is done what I had to do is, change setupClass to setup and then replace cls with self , ok for now it solves my problem but no it will run setup for each test, it would be good if setup is run once, token is generated and  then  can be used in each test, Thankyou

Comment: Let me post a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following up from the comments section:

Here's a sample answer on how to declare and initialize token in one method and access in another.

```py
import unittest

class Example(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print("Print me only once")
        cls.token = 100 # Initilze your token here using auth route
    def test1(self):
        print(1)
        print('Token = ', self.token) # Prints Token = 100
    def test2(myself): # Although self is preferred
        print(2)
        print('Token = ', myself.token) # Prints Token = 100

unittest.main()
```